# JSP Javascript not working Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I am currently trying to set up a small web application where people can upload, rate and download files. The backend is done, now only the front end part is missing.
I am doing this with java server pages.

Problem is: I want to avoid reloading the page each time i change my search options, so i wanted to use async&await from javascript for this.
Now theoretically my script *can* fetch the needed data from the backend. When a button is clicked, this function will be executed:

```
async function searchDatabase() {
const edtSearchText = document.getElementById("edtSearchOption");
const sltSorting = document.getElementById("sltSortingOption");
const sltOrdering = document.getElementById("sltOrderingOption");

var searchOption = edtSearchText.value;
var sortingOption = sltSorting.value;
var orderOption sltOrdering.value;

const url = "/search";

var data = new FormData();
data.append("search", searchOption);
data.append("sorting", sortingOption);
data.append("ordering", orderOption);

var requestParams = {
    method: 'GET',
    body: data,
    redirect: 'follow'
};

let response = await fetch(url, requestParams);
let data = await response.json(); }
```

Now when i access my page in the browser, it shows the data normally, now i want to search something so i put in data in my form and click the button.
The problems are the following:

1. It seems to still want to reload the page
2. I get this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: searchDatabase is not defined
   onsubmit http://localhost:8081/?search=&sorting=date_upload&ordering=1:1"
   I tried the whole day to fix this problem and hope that you can help me here.

This is the code of welcome.jsp, the site i am accessing: https://pastebin.com/g6PRV5Au

If you need more details please let me know.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Call your method searchDabase() while submitting the form as mentioned below.

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return searchDatabase();">
```

And return false from end of the method like below.

```
function searchDatabase(){
// your code......
return false;
}
```

Happy learning :)

Comment: @[dertoaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14443844/dertoaster) i hope it worked for you.

Comment: Yes, sort of. It turned out the problems came from syntax errors -.-, but your answer made me look over the code again and then i noticed them. It works fine now, thank you